# WordPress - Click download link to display popup form

Tags: html, wordpress, download

Our website is currently being created on WordPress, and we will soon have a large resource centre for PDF downloads. We need to be able to capture user data before customers download the PDF files - however we need to keep the forms hidden and only display the download title, before clicking on the link.

Is there a plugin or some code already created that can do the following:

- Using download monitor (or another plugin), add an extra checkbox field labelled 'Request a form'
- If the 'Request a form' checkbox is ticked, when a user clicks on that download link, an overlay form will appear
- Once they've filled in the form details their download will automatically be emailed to them.

Any help would be much appreciated, or any other suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Looking for the same thing, any progress? Im looking for the same Form to Download Link protection, for each link to a download file to pop-up a contact form before you can download.